# how to change the index of directory page in apache?

Tags: apache-2.2, ubuntu, directoryindex

How can I change the page that Apache shows when someone navigates to a directory that does not have the index page? I would like to change that page to not be so easy to view all files in a directory.
How can I do this without having to put an index page in each directory?

Answer (score 3):

Add `Options -Indexes` into your `httpd.conf` or appropriate `.htaccess` file.